# Why find() doesn't work for string in the format of character array?

Tags: c++, string

I have code below. I would like to delimit `myStr` by using `find()`. But I got error message `error: request for member 'find' in 'myStr', which is of non-class type 'char [50]'`.

How can I fix it?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
   char myStr[50] = "Hello-World";
   int posi =  myStr.find("-", 0);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `myStr` is not of a class type, and therefore doesn't have member functions, named `find` or otherwise. The right way to fix it depends on whether your code is meant to be C or C++. Choose one: I observe you tagged your questions with both tags - one of those must be wrong.

Comment: "How can I fix it?" use `std::string` instead of char array

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik If I need to use `char myStr[50]`, then what should I use to replace `.find`?

Comment: Well, if for some unfathomable reason you are unable or unwilling to use `std::string` - a C++ class specifically designed for string manipulation - then there's `strchr`, a C language function to find a character in a null-terminated character array (also known as a C-style string).

Comment: Thanks for your help. `strchr` works, and finally I use `strstr`.

Answer (score 0):

char type is not a class so it does not have methods. Try using string class instead, ex:

```
string myStr = "Hello-World";
int posi = myStr.find("-", 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The C++ `string` class has a `find` member function. C-style character arrays do not.

*C and C++ are different languages*.  What you're looking for is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
   std::string myStr = "Hello-World";
   int posi = myStr.find("-", 0);
   return 0;
}
```

But you don't need either of those includes. You do need to `#include <string>` to have access to C++'s `string` class.

```
#include <string>

int main() {
   std::string myStr = "Hello-World";
   int posi = myStr.find("-", 0);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I really need to use `char myStr[50]`. Then what should I use to replace `.find`? In fact, what I need is a delimiter from the right for a long string. `strtok()` is from the left, but I need the right-direction-version.

Comment: Can you reverse both strings? If you can, then hopefully you can figure out how to find the index from the right. And if you must write C code in C++, you should use the proper includes. `#include <cstdio>` and `#include <cstring>`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Finally I use `strstr` to get the problem solved.